# Merging branches in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, merge, branch

Currently I have two branches in a Mercurial repository. One the "default" branch where I do most of my development and another a "production" one where the code that is currently live goes.

My question is how do I "merge" my default branch with the production one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do

```
$ hg update production
$ hg merge default
```

to bring in the new stuff from `default` into the `production` branch. You'll have to resolve any merge conflicts at this point. There is no chance of **data loss** since you are working with **committed changes**. You can abort the merge with `hg update -C` and you can re-do the merge of a file `foo.c` with

```
$ hg resolve foo.c
```

When you're satisfied with the merge, you run

```
$ hg commit
```

to create a merge changeset that describes how the two branches should be merged.

There are many tutorials on this, for example:

- [Mercurial wiki](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TutorialMerge)
- [Task based development](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/tasks/)